# Setting authentication modes with Owin and IIS hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, owin

I currently have a self hosted OWIN WebAPI service which is using windows authentication mode for certain URLs and Anonymous for pretty much most other URLs using the following code in App Startup (startup.cs):

```
if (app.Properties.ContainsKey("System.Net.HttpListener"))
        {
            HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
            listener.AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate = request =>
            {
                var restrictedAuthenticationScheme = (AuthenticationSchemes)AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
                var scheme =
                    request.RawUrl.IndexOf("internal", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                    || request.RawUrl.IndexOf("admin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                ? restrictedAuthenticationScheme // use intergated for internal or admin end points only
                    : AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
                Logger.LogInfo(string.Format("Request : {0}, Authentication Scheme {1}", request.RawUrl, scheme.ToString()));
                return scheme;
            };
            listener.Start();
        }
```

However, when running under IIS, there doesn't seem to be an HTTPListener so app.properties (app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"] is non-existent), so the key count is 12 but when self hosted it's 13. Any ideas, how I'm supposed to handle this?
Hopefully, I have included enough detail but let me know.